# Prevent AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior from adding top margin to the view?

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I'm trying to achieve a layout where my view will extend all the way across the screen, under the `ActionBar`, and the ActionBar will be transparent. I also need the `ActionBar` and `BottomNavigationView` to hide on scroll, so I'm using `CoordinatorLayout`.

I'm using the AppCompat theme with the attribute `<item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>` in order to have my views extend under the ActionBar. However, after adding `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to my container Fragment, the view gets placed below the ActionBar.

Is there a way to prevent this part of the `appbar_scrolling_behaviour`? I've tried without the behaviour, but the scrolling of the AppBar is not synced witht he RecyclerView scrolling underneath it. Thank you!

Here's a [gif of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObjJc.jpg)

P.S.: I'm trying to use the Android Navigation Component, so I'm following a single activity, multi fragment architecture, if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and make some changes because i used androidx..
make main layout like this way..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white">


<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:theme="@style/MyToolbar"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/MyToolbar">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/headerIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_6sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_edit_location_black"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_6sdp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/header"
                style="@style/MyToolbar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/primary"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivSearch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:src="@drawable/search_icon"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomContainer"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout" />


    <RelativeLayout
       android:id="@+id/bottomContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bvTabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/Widget.BottomNavigationView"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/navigation_drawable_tint"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/navigation_drawable_tint"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu_item" />


    </RelativeLayout>

 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however, using your layout does not hide the ActionBar or botton navigaiton bar on scroll. That's why I'm using a `CoordinatorLayout`.

Comment: because according my code appbar and bottom between define content part. when you load fragment that content part your scroll only that part. that time your appbar and bottombar not move

Comment: Did you find any solution for your problem?